# If possible use nginx to redirect by location to node app?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, ssl, nginx

I have an **Angular application** in a directory (frontend), and **NodeJS application** (backend API REST) in another directory in my EC2 machine. And I have a SSL certificate for `mydomain.com`

- The frontend (Angular App) is served by Nginx in `mydomain.com`
- The backend (NodeJS API REST) is running at port 3000, and all their routes are like `/api/whatever/`

I would like to use my SSL certificate for frontend and backend, behind the same domain through NGINX.

My question is, In Nginx is it possible redirect all the requests like `mydomain.com/api/whatever` to NodeJS backend and all the requests like `mydomain.com/angularRoutes` to frontend folder?

My Nginx configuration file is like this:

```
upstream {
    server apinode 127.0.0.1:3000 max_fails=0;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mydomain.com;
    rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri permanent;
}

server {
   listen 80;
   server_name www.mydomain.com;
   rewrite ^(.*)$ $scheme://domain.com$1;
}

server {
   listen 443;
   server_name mydomain.com;

   ssl_on;
   ssl_certificate /path/to/server.crt;
   ssl_certificate_key /path/to/server.key;

   location / {
       root /home/ubuntu/frontend;
       index index.htm index.html;
   }

}
```

and I would like to add the following:

```
location /api/ {
    proxy_pass: http://apinode
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
}
```

It is possible? What I need to change/add/remove?

Thank you so much!

Comment: You have syntax error in `upstream` block and missed semicolon after `proxy_pass` in `location /api/` block

Comment: Thx @AlexeyTen, I have noticed too. I have test other location config like:

location /api {
                proxy_pass              http://localhost:3000/api;
                proxy_buffering         on;
        }

and works fine! :)