# Nginx setup for angular app with node API

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, nginx

I have been building API using express and front end using angular. Both are in different directory named `/var/www/apps/client` and `/var/www/apps/server`.

I want to deploy my application using nginx as a webserver. I am able to host angular application but when trying to request my API getting following error on browser.

`Mixed Content: The page at 'https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3000/api/videos'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`

Nginx config

```
server { 
  listen  80;
  server_name localhost;
  access_log /var/log/client/access.log;
  error_log  /var/log/client/error.log;
  root /var/www/apps/client/dist;
  charset utf-8;

   location / {
    rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
   }
 }
server {
  listen        443 ssl;
  server_name  localhost;
  access_log /var/log/client/access.log;
  error_log  /var/log/client/error.log;
  ssl_certificate       /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key   /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;

  keepalive_timeout 5;
  root /var/www/apps/client/dist;
  charset utf-8;

  location ~ ^/(scripts.*js|styles|images) {
    gzip_static on;
    expires 1y;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
    add_header ETag "";

    break;
  }

  location / {
    try_files $uri /index.html;
  }
}
```

My express server code -

```
var express = require("express"),
  app = express(),
  mongoose = require("mongoose"),
  config = require("./config");

app.set("appPath", config.root);

mongoose.connect(config.mongo.uri, config.mongo.options);

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  "use strict";

  // Website you wish to allow to connect
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  // Request methods you wish to allow
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE");

  // Request headers you wish to allow
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "X-Requested-With,content-type,api_key,adminid,userid");

  // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the    requests sent
  // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);

  // Pass to next layer of middleware
  next();
});

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  "use strict";

  next();
});


require("./routes")(app);
app.listen(config.port);

console.log("Listening on port " + config.port)
```

Serving API at `3000` port. I found this [If possible use nginx to redirect by location to node app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24528955/if-possible-use-nginx-to-redirect-by-location-to-node-app)
But this is also not working. Any kind of help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think, the issue is completely with your nginx config. The error message implies that the initial connection from the browser and nginx server was over https. And then you are trying to make an insecure connection through XMLHttpRequest with http.

Solution:

1. Either load up the initial connection as insecure i.e http
2. Or make your XMLHttpRequest with a secure connection i.e https.

To help with the config file

```
# For http
server {
  listen 80
  server_name localhost
  access_log /var/log/client/access.log
  error_log /var/log/client/error.log
  root /var/www/apps/client/dist
  charset utf-8

     location / {
         proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
         proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
         proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

         proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
     }
}

# For https
server {
  listen 443 ssl
  server_name localhost
  access_log /var/log/client/access.log
  error_log /var/log/client/error.log

  ssl_certificate       /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key   /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;
  root /var/www/apps/client/dist
  charset utf-8

     location / {
         proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
         proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
         proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

         proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
     }
}
```

Restart Nginx

```
sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart
```

Comment: If I use  proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/; then root /var/www/apps/client/dist wont be accessible, I mean it is not loading the angular directory page, It is loading node API response on accessing IP.

Comment: 'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3000/api/videos is under /var/www/apps/client/dist ? .. am not on my ubuntu machine, so i can't do tests.

Comment: No its not, Both are in separate folder.

Comment: please add your express server to the question above

Comment: instead of doing a rewrite, just do a complete proxy and remove the root directive, its not necessary and mount ur express app properly.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is the other endpoint which you are hitting internally is not Https protected, because of which you are getting the error

```
http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3000/api/videos
```

So, you should write a separate config for client to make the connection https secured. Add that proxy pass also to redirect all your request coming to port 443 to 3000 similar what you did for server

```
location / {
         proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
         proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
         proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

         proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
     }
```

Make sure ports are different for node and client app